# Ruby Test::UnitTest of nil SimpleDelegator

Tags: ruby

```
require 'delegate'

class Fred < SimpleDelegator

  def initialize( s )
    super
  end
end

puts Fred.new( [] ) == []      # ==> true
puts Fred.new( {} ) == {}      # ==> true  
puts Fred.new( nil ) == nil    # ==> true
```

but

```
require 'test/unit'
class FredTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_nilliness
    assert_nil Fred.new( nil )
  end
end
```

returns...
Running tests:

F

Finished tests in 0.000501s, 1996.0080 tests/s, 1996.0080 assertions/s.

1) Failure:
test_nilliness:20
Expected nil to be nil.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Huh?  Is assert_nil checking for NilClass?  That would fail in this case.

Comment: Since you did not specify a ruby version the 2 answers below should take care of this for you depending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test/unit's #assert_nil method is calling #nil? to find out if the object is nil.  The problem is that Object, which is in Fred's ancestor chain, defines #nil?.  Since SimpleDelegator only delegates missing methods, #nil? is returning the result for Fred, not for the delegatee.

to work around this, you can define nil? and forward to the delegatee yourself:

```
def nil?
  __getobj__.nil?
end
```

This answer also applies to minitest.

Comment: Can you point me to where `#nil?` is being called because I don't see this in the Docs anywhere but your method does work. How does this work where does this happen?

Comment: @engineersmnky https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/2c269ed351d8583da075cdfc6bfc3542ca1c5fce/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L236

Comment: Thank you. I was only looking at `Test::Unit::Assertions` and not at `MiniTest::Assertions`. +1

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh, that's funny.  I looked in the wrong library, but got the right answer by coincidence.  Here's the right library: Click on "view source".  It, also, is using #nil?  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_not_nil

Comment: I see I accidentally looked at 1.8.7 docs which included `assert_nil` [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html) in `Test::Unit::Assertions` seems it was moved to `MiniTest::Assertions` module in >1.8.7 and then that module is included in `Test::Unit::Assertion` nice.

Comment: @engineersmnky I didn't realize the web was that tangled.  Thanks for deciphering it!

Answer (score 0):

"Huh? Is assert_nil checking for NilClass? That would fail in this case."

1.8.7 in `Test::Unit::Assertions` but for >1.8.7 look at `MiniTest::Assertions` and see @WayneConrad's answer/comments as this is correct.

Not exactly it checks the classes against each other becuase everything else failed but the string representations are the same.  If you look at the source it uses `assert_equal` which checks the following:

are the `pretty_inspect` strings the same (in your case yes) `if exp_str == act_str`

```
  Fred.new(nil).pretty_inspect.chomp #=> "nil"
  nil.pretty_inspect.chomp           #=> "nil"
```

are the objects both Strings or both Regex (in your case no) `if (exp.is_a?(String) && act.is_a?(String)) ||(exp.is_a?(Regexp) && act.is_a?(Regexp))`

are the objects both Floats (in your case no) `elsif exp.is_a?(Float) && act.is_a?(Float)`

are the objects both Time (in your case no) `elsif exp.is_a?(Time) && act.is_a?(Time)`

are the classes unequal (in your case yes) `elsif exp.class != act.class`

```
  Fred.new(nil).class #=> Fred
  nil.class           #=> NilClass
```

message then equals `"<#{exp_str}>#{exp_comment} expected but was\n<#{act_str}>#{act_comment}"`

where `exp_str` and `act_str` will be the `pretty_inspect` strings and `exp_comment` and `act_comment` are the object classes. So technically this message will read

```
"<nil>NilClass expected but was\n<nil>Fred"
```

It then uses `===` to compare them and passes that to `assert`

```
nil === Fred.new(nil)   #=> false
```

Here is the Docs

[assert_nil](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_nil)

[assert_equal](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_equal)